# BeautifulSoup to find text within <img alt tag

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Here is what I get back from this Python line of code

```
listm = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'thumb'})
```

when I iterate over the listm, here is an example of a item...

```
<a href="/property-search/property-details/1021206?StrtNum=1507"><img alt="1507 BOSTWICK LN" src="/res/slir/w75-h57-c4:3/propertyimages/20120904/BB/DSCN0738.JPG"/></a>
```

However, what I really want is the "1507 BOSTWICK LN" within the `<img alt=`

I have tried the `.get_text` with returns a blank, I've tried 
`lista = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'thumb'},{'alt':'img'})`, and several other variations that do not get me the text.

I would like to have BeautifulSoup return the text, or would a regular expression work? My knowledge of of RE is zilch, any input would greatly be appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
listm = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'thumb'})
for elem in listm:
    print elem('img')[0]['alt']
```

This should find the `img` tag within each `td` and print the values of the `alt` attribute.

EDIT:

You should not assume the existence of the `img` tag. Do this instead:

```
listm = soup.findAll('td',{'class':'thumb'})
for elem in listm:
    imgs = elem('img')
    if imgs:
        print imgs['alt']
```

Comment: Hi; Thanks you both for your great responses! Is there any difference between using if imgs: print imgs['alt'] OR if imgs is not None: print imgs?

Comment: As far as whether or not it will work, there is no difference. According to PEP8 however, `if imgs:` is appropriate. Link here: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: If this answer helped you, you should accept it as correct =)

Answer (score 3):

Your `td` elements contain some nested elements; search for the `img` tag within each `td` element, then take the `alt` attribute with an item lookup:

```
for td in listm:
    img = td.find('img')
    if img is not None:
        print img['alt']
```

Comment: No worries =) You're just quicker on the draw, I suppose! Besides, your answer is better. I don't check for an `img` tag. I just assume its existence.